# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many through other table with name instead id and get additional data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, many-to-many

I have two main tables, Posts and Categories which should have a many-to-many relationship.
I know you can just do it with a table called category_post but thats not how the structure I'm able to work with is set up.

It is like this:
Posts have a one-to-one relation with questions and questions have categories through the posts.

My database looks like this:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('contet');
}

Schema::create('post_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('post_id');
    $table->integer('views');
    $table->integer('answers');
}

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
}

Schema::create('post_question_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('post_question_id');
    $table->string('category_name');
    $table->string('additional_info');
}
```

As you can see, my pivot table does neither have a post_id nor a category_id but a post_question_id and a category_name which is unique in categories table. But the should-be state is a many-to-many with posts and categories.

Questions also have a One-To-Many relation to query additional_infos

This are my models:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PostQuestion')->with('categories');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostQuestionCategory');
    }
}

class PostQuestionCategory extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PostQuestion')->with('post');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {

    }
}
```

So this is where the fun begins:
I want to query all posts from one category. I already tried and got this by 3 approaches:

1.

```
public function posts()
{
    $name = $this->name;

    return Post::whereHas('question', function ($question) use ($name) {
        $question->whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use ($name) {
            $categories->where('name', $name);
        });
    })->get();
}
```

2.

```
public function posts()
{
    return PostQuestionCategory::with('question')->where('name', $this->name)->get();
}
```

3.
Adding post_id and category_id to the table

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_question_categories');
}
```

The third is not a real option sine I don't want to manipulate the existing database.
In the second I dont really get the post object as a relation but just as a plain query result.

Also when I do in category/show.blade.php

```
@foreach ($category->posts() as $post)
   {{ $post->question->categories }}
@endforeach
```

I dont have access to many attributes because of that.

So I prefer using the first option.

The thing is:

I only want to get the categories which are the current I'm currently on. 
With that query I'll get indeed all posts which have that, but in the foreach I'll also get all additional categories. 
Furthermore I want to get the additional_info attribute in this instance.

Like this:
I'm on route categories.show/1 (name = cat1)

and my database is like

posts

```
id   title
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

post_questions

```
id    post_id   views   answers
1     1         12      2
2     2         7       0
3     3         456     6
4     4         124     11
```

post_question_categories:

```
id  question_id   additional_info       category_name
1   1             ai1                   cat 1
2   1             ai2                   cat 2
3   3             ai1                   cat 1
4   4             ai1                   cat 3
```

categories

```
id  name
1   cat 1
2   cat 2
3   cat 3
```

My ideal output would be:

```
posts 
[
    {id: 1, title: 'a', question: {id: 1, views: 12, answers: 2, categories: [{id: 1, additional_info: 'ai1', name: 'cat1'}, // Not id 2 since im on show/1]}, 
    {id: 3, title: 'c', question: {id: 3, views: 456, answers: 6, categories: [{id: 1, additional_info: 'ai1', name: 'cat1'}}
]
```

I hope this is not too confusing and someone can help me!

Comment: actually, since the categories is many-to-many although, but can be only once at this post found, the output would be better if categories isn't an array but a single object

Comment: `PostQuestionCategory` should extend Pivot (i.e. not Model).

Comment: why in your post_question_categories, you are using the name of categories only not with id itself ? like category_id = category id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second one query already solved your problem. Just do some modification to it like this.

```
public function posts()
{
    return PostQuestionCategory::with('question.post')->where('category_name', $this->name)->get();
}
```

just add post together with question to be able to include it in the returned collection.

or if you have a relationship also with categories then you just add also the category relationship, like this one

```
 public function posts()
 {
        return PostQuestionCategory::with('question.post', 'category')->where('category_name', $this->name)->get();
 }
```

Comment: Yeah youre, right, I had the right approach but didn't think it till the end. I just need to proper use my huge amount of data I get in this output array and I have all I need.

Comment: Actually it's not needed to say with('question.post') since my question function in PostQuestionCategory Class already does that